# Adding Columns to the "Related Work" section of WIT page

Tags: azure-devops

How can I can control the list of columns that are displayed when you maximize the "Related Work" section on a WIT page?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59nsE.png)

Comment: so you want to edit the "Related Work" Group in the work item to have more columns?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Team service then the answer is "No" you cannot edit the "Related Work" Group in the WIT.

On the other hand if you are using TFS, then you can explore on WIT Admin and XML options. For more refer here  [Customize Work Item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/change-work-item-form-layout)

Hope this Helps!